# Problem with Android emulator no longer starting on mac os high sierrra 10.13.6

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, macos-high-sierra, android-studio-4.1

I have a late 2011 Mac with a 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB and 12 GB of ram.I've had no problems with starting the android emulator from Android Studio in the past. However, updating to Android Studio 4.1.1 the emulator no longer launches. It looks like it's going to launch however it crashes and I get an error report that looks like this:
[Android Emulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWCdd.png)

I have no clue what to do. I've uninstalled and reinstalled intel haxm, started and stopped it, tried to launch the android emulator with the terminal, uninstall and reinstall the emulator, wiped my hard drive and reinstall mac os high sierra (latest version for my computer) and still nothing. Is it just not compatible with my computer anymore?

Comment: Just as a reference, running High Sierra 10.13.6 on a MacBook Pro Mid-2012, 2.3 GHz  i7, 8GB RAM, NVIDIA GT 650M/Intel HD 4000, Android Studio 4.1.1, Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2, Emulator 30.2.6, Android Platform Tools 30.0.5, HAXM 7.5.1: I'm able to create a new AVD Pixel 2 Android 11 rev 3 and it runs without issue.

Comment: Same Error Gilie, did you find a solution? (if you switch your avd to software accelrations it works)

Comment: No I wasn’t able to find a solution at all. It ran really slow when I chose to run it on software and I could not work with it. I read something about the release of Big Sur causing lots of problems for high Sierra and since I couldn’t upgrade my Mac to the latest operating system I decided to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Android emulator 29.0.6 (May 1, 2019) is probably the start of problems...

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#29.0.6-vulkan-macos

> macOS support is still experimental, but the emulator already includes the Swiftshader, MoltenVK, and libportability (gfx-rs) APIs.

It's not easy to install old versions of the emulator, but I can run the current emulator (30.0.26) on my MacBook Pro "Early 2011" if I request either swiftshader or libportability. If I request moltenvk, it crashes (same crash if I don't select one - looks like the crash you posted).

```
# crash
emulator -avd AVD
ANDROID_EMU_VK_ICD=moltenvk emulator -avd AVD

# works
ANDROID_EMU_VK_ICD=swiftshader emulator -avd AVD
ANDROID_EMU_VK_ICD=portability emulator -avd AVD
```

It looks like swiftshader is entirely CPU-based while libportability may be able to take advantage of 3D hardware?

MoltenVK requires Metal, which I do not have (why I can't upgrade to 10.14). It seems your system also lacks Metal.